# Delete field from old java class implementing Serializable

Tags: java, serialization

Suppose i have version of class `MyClass`  where i have two fields `int count` and `String name`. And i have persisted the byte stream to file. After i delete the attribute `name` from the class then also the persisted byte stream is getting converted to object with no issues.

But as per the  `Serializable` docs `adding new attribute is compatible change but deleting attribute is incompatible change w.r.t. Serilaization`.  I am confused can somebody please help  me understanding this. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 11):

A few points:

When an object is deserialized, any fields *not* found in the byte-stream will be initialized to `null`. Therefore, when you *add* a new field, when a new version object is deserialized from an old version byte-stream, the new field will be initialized to `null`. If `null` is considered to be an invalid value, you can provide a `readObject` method to handle conversion. Old versions can still be deserialized from the new byte-stream- the new field is just ignored.

If a field is *deleted*, the situation is reversed: the old version class will now be missing a field. The missing field will be set to `null`. However, unlike the previous case, the old version can't add a `readObject` method (if you could add that method, then it would become the latest *new version*). Hence, deleting a field is considered to be **incompatible**.

In summary, the ability to create a `readObject` method in the new version class allows it to cope with the old version byte-stream when a new field is added. Unfortunately, the reverse is not possible.

It is important to note that, unless specifically defined, the `serialVersionUID` field will be automatically generated and will most likely change with practically all notable changes to a class. If two class versions have different `serialVersionUID`, an exception will be thrown when trying to carry out serialization/deserialization on a older or newer version byte-stream. If you don't manually set `serialVersionUID`, then no versions of your class will be compatible in terms of serialization.

P.S. If `null` happens to be a valid state for the deleted field (in the old version), then I guess you will be okay to delete fields. However, that is probably an edge case.

Comment: nice explanation. And problable your last statement is the main point of concern for me. In may case `NULL` is valid case that's why i was getting confused. You are right i think "if null is not a valid case for you than deleting field is not compatible". Am i correct?

Comment: Yea, I just tested it. It compiles and runs (when deleting a field). One thought though, if `null` is a valid value, it would bring in to question why the field wasn't made `transient` in the original class.

Comment: Another option would be to create a `writeObject` method which would write a default value for the removed field when serialized. The logic being that a default field may be more suitable than `null`. However, this introduces some questionable dependencies.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The new version of the class *can* add a readObject() method. The point is that there's nothing much useful you can put into it to deal with the deleted field. However as the field was deleted, presumably the OP doesn't care what value is in the stream for it, whether null or otherwise. I really fail to see what your last paragraph is even about.

Comment: I have only suggested writing a `readObject` method in the event that a field is added. Which paragraph are you concerned about: the last paragraph of my answer, or one of my comments?

Comment: I am concerned about the paragraph that talks about the *old version* adding a `readObject()` method, which is pointless and needless, and about the paragraph that says it is OK to delete fields if 'null' is an OK case, which is meaningless. He wouldn't be doing it if he needed a value in the field.

Comment: I specifically state that the _old version_ **can't** add a `readObject()`. 'Okay to delete fields' refers to serialization not being broken. The debate is not whether to delete fields, but weather serialization still works after doing so.

Comment: «If you don't manually set serialVersionUID, then no versions of your class will be compatible in terms of serialization.»
--
In this case you can use the `serialver` utility on the old version of the class that misses serialVersionUID and use this generated one in the new version of class. (see Effective Java by Joshua Bloch for more great tips for Java Programming)

Answer (score 4):

*Provided the serialVersionUID remains the same,* field addition and deletion are both compatible under the rules defined in the Object Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specifcation, which you should certainly read.

Comment: Section 5.6.1 specifically lists removing a field as an incompatible change: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6519 It is important to note that 'incompatible' is interpreted as: 'the guarantee of interoperability cannot be maintained'

Comment: @Mowgli That section refers to a possible *application* incompatibility. It also says that the serialization and deserialization part works correctly in the case where the stream from the old class contains the value and the new class doesn't: " the value of the field will be set to the default value because no value is available in the stream".

Comment: I can confirm that deleting field is okay and my serializable file loads fine even after I deleted a field.